# Qt slot from thread called more than once

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots

I have created a class CalculationManager which has a public slot process() emitting a signal finished().

```
void CalculationManager::process()
{
    cout << "calc FFT: process()" << endl;
    ...
    emit finished();
}
```

This is used with a QThread from the gui (calculationManager is a QScopedPointer)

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButtonStartFFT_clicked()
{
    cout << "on_pushButtonStartFFT_clicked()" << endl;

    ...
    calculationManager->moveToThread(thread);

    connect(thread, SIGNAL (started()), calculationManager.data(), SLOT (process()));
    connect(calculationManager.data(), SIGNAL (finished()), thread, SLOT (quit()));
    connect(calculationManager.data(), SIGNAL (finished()), this, SLOT (getResultsAndPlot()));

    cout << "FFT thread started." << endl;
    thread->start();
}
```

with a slot for the plots

```
void MainWindow::getResultsAndPlot()
{
    fftAction doShift = static_cast<fftAction>(calculationManager->shiftBeforeFFT());

    updatePlotData(ui->qplot1, calculationManager->data(doShift) );
    cout << "update plots" << endl;
}
```

At startup of the gui the function is called. and the output is as expected:

```
on_pushButtonStartFFT_clicked()
FFT thread started.
calc FFT: process()
update plots
```

however every further click on the buttons calls process multiple times and getResultsAndPlot() even more often. I have not clue why this happens. How can I debug or solve this ?

```
on_pushButtonStartFFT_clicked()
FFT thread started.
calc FFT: process()
calc FFT: process()
update plots
update plots
update plots
update plots
on_pushButtonStartFFT_clicked()
FFT thread started.
calc FFT: process()
calc FFT: process()
calc FFT: process()
update plots
update plots
update plots
update plots
update plots
update plots
update plots
update plots
update plots
```

Comment: if you really want to connect the signals and slots from inside the slot's scope you need to pass `Qt::UniqueConnection` to `connect` like: `connect(thread, SIGNAL (started()), calculationManager.data(), SLOT (process()), Qt::UniqueConnection);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530590/qt-signals-and-slot-connected-twice-what-happens (duplicate ?)

Answer (score 4):

Every time you click the button, you create this connections

```
connect(thread, SIGNAL (started()), calculationManager.data(), SLOT (process()));
connect(calculationManager.data(), SIGNAL (finished()), thread, SLOT (quit()));
connect(calculationManager.data(), SIGNAL (finished()), this, SLOT (getResultsAndPlot()));
```

So, after first click there is one connection and slot `process()` called once. After second click there are two connections and this slot called twice. And so on. Just make this connections outside slot `on_pushButtonStartFFT_clicked()`.

Answer (score 1):

Doing all connections withint the pushbotton slot was the reason. The connection is thus done multiple times.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButtonStartFFT_clicked()
{
    ...
    connect(thread, SIGNAL (started()), calculationManager.data(), SLOT (process()));
}
```

Once this is moved to the gui constructor everything works fine

Comment: Yes, that's what @Evgeny described before...

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Matthias Pospiech. One option you have if you want to use connect on button click is to use disconnect before connect, as per http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#disconnect ... This way you ensure that your signal is connected only one time ...  for example,

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButtonStartFFT_clicked()
{
... 

 disconnect(thread, SIGNAL (started()), calculationManager.data(), SLOT(process()));
 connect(thread, SIGNAL (started()), calculationManager.data(), SLOT(process())); 

...
}
```